# Why are my Postgresql sessions writing directly on disk?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a write-heavy application on a PostgreSQL 9.4 on CentOS 6 that I'm trying to tune.

Using iotop, I see that my session processers are doing all the heavy writing on disk when (to my understanding) only the checkpointer and writer processes should be doing it.

I thought that the sessions might be writing temp files due to lack of workmem but when I query the pg_stat_database, the columns "temp_files" and "temp_bytes" are zero. I'm trying to log this kind of usage via system parameter "log_temp_files" but nothing appears on the log files.

Can somebody help me? Are there any kind of data that the sessions write directly on disk besides temp files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have often wondered about this myself.

Comment: wonder if you might get better answer(s) over at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I will try asking there too. Thank you